# How to fit a random effect only model using glmmTMB in R?

Tags: mixed-models, random-effects, glmmtmb

I want to fit a random effect model using the glmmTMB function in R. I specified the model to be as model = glmmTMB(Y ~ (1+x1+x2|group)). The estimation results still contain a universal intercept stored in obj$env$last.par.best[1] as beta, even though I did not put a 1 as a universal intercept outside of the random part. Anyone knows how to fit a random effect only model using glmmTMB? Thanks!

The reason I want a random effect only model is because I have a panel data with many groups, and each group has a very different relationship between y and the x's. So basically I just want one model for each group. I thought glmmTMB is able to help me achieve that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand the motivation, but it's straightforward to implement this in any of the common packages using `-1` in the formula to remove the constant from the fixed effects design matrix. Here is an example using the data from `lme4::sleepstudy`

```
library('glmmTMB')
df <- lme4::sleepstudy
names(df) <- tolower(names(df))

m1 <- glmmTMB(formula = reaction ~ -1 + (days|subject), data = df)
summary(m1)
# Family: gaussian  ( identity )
# Formula:          reaction ~ -1 + (days | subject)
# Data: df
# 
# AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
# 1840.8   1853.6   -916.4   1832.8      176 
# 
# Random effects:
#   
#   Conditional model:
#   Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev. Corr 
# subject  (Intercept) 63770.1  252.53        
# days          142.2   11.93   0.88 
# Residual               654.9   25.59        
# Number of obs: 180, groups:  subject, 18
# 
# Dispersion estimate for gaussian family (sigma^2):  655
```